# HbaseStorageHandler plugin in Drill

Tags: hadoop, apache-drill

I am able to query hive,hbase individually by using Drill.Now i am trying to query HbaseStorageHandler type tables in hive. For this in Drill, Hive Storage Plugin I added these properties as,

```
{
  "type": "hive",
  "enabled": true,
  "configProps": {
    "hive.metastore.uris": "thrift://trinitybdClusterM02.trinitymobility.local:9083",
    "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true",
    "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir": "/tmp/drill_hive_wh",
    "fs.default.name": "hdfs://trinitybdClusterM02.trinitymobility.local:9000",
    "hive.metastore.sasl.enabled": "false",
    "hbase.zookeeper.quorum": "localhost",
    "hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort": "2181"
  }
}
```

I tried to query like,

0: jdbc:drill:zk=localhost> use hive.test;
   0: jdbc:drill:zk=localhost> select * from twitter_test_nlp limit 1;

It is giving error as,

```
Error: SYSTEM ERROR: NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan.setAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;[B)V

Fragment 0:0

[Error Id: fc3994f4-7d7e-475e-870b-259ac91ea81a on trinitybdClusterM02.trinitymobility.local:31010] (state=,code=0)
```

Anybody is using this type please share me what properties I have to add for query HBaseStorageHandler tables of Hive.

Comment: what is the Drill version you are using ? Also can you check the hbase-client version under <Drill_installation_directory>jars/3rdparty folder.

Comment: I am using Drill 1.8.0 and in drill directory I have     drill/jars/3rdparty/hbase-client-1.1.3.jar  file.

Comment: I am using Hbase 0.98.9.hive 1.2.1 and Hadoop 2.6.0.

Comment: anybody have any idea please share with me.

Comment: looking at the Scan class both in github and hbase client 1.1.3 packaged in drill 1.8.0. setAttribute (string name, byte[] value) method is present. Which leads to suspecting some other version of hbase-client jar is in your classpath which is getting loaded before hbase client 1.1.3 from drill. Can you examine your classpath and print the same here ? https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.java

Comment: anybody is using drill with these versions please share me how to get HBaseStorageHandler tablesin drill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In drill 1.9 this problem has resolved. drill 1.9 directly supports HbaseStorageHandler tables(Hive and hbase integrated tables) also with hive storage plug-in.And it directly supports spatial queries also like st_contains() etc.So if anybody need these type of requirements use drill 1.9.0.